# Where to import?

Tags: python

I'm learning Python and today while writing some code I was trying to decide where to put an `import` statement.

I can put an import statement just about anywhere it seems but how does the placement affect performance, the namespace, and anything else I don't know yet?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The official GoodPractice is to put all your imports at the beginning of your module or script, starting with standard lib modules / packages, then third part, then project specific, cf http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#imports

Practically, you sometimes have to defer the import into a function as a quick&dirty workaround for a circular dependency (the correct way to solve a circular dependency is to extract the relevant parts in another module, but with some frameworks you may have to accept the Q&D workaround).

Deferring the import into a function for "performances" reasons is not a good idea IMHO but once again you sometimes have to break the rules.

Importing a module really means:

```
search the module_or_package in `sys.modules`
if not found:
    search the module_or_package_source in `sys.path`
    if not found:
        raise an ImportError
    create a `module` instance from the module_or_package_source 
    # -> imply executing the top-level source code, which may raise anything
    store the `module` instance in `sys.modules`
bind the `module` name (or whatever name was imported from it) in the current namespace
```

wrt/ what "current namespace" means, it's really this: the namespace (module's "global", function's "local" or `class` statement's body) in which the `import` statement is executed. Here's a simple script with all three examples:

```
try:
    re
except NameError, e:
    print "name 're' is not yet defined in the module's namespace"
    print "module namespace : %s" % globals()

import re
print "name 're' is now defined in the module's namespace"
print "module namespace : %s" % globals()


def foo():
    try:
        os
    except NameError, e:
        print "name 'os' is not yet defined in the function's namespace"
        print "function namespace : %s" % locals()
        print "name 'os' is not defined in the module's namespace neither"
        print "module namespace : %s" % globals()

    import os
    print "name 'os' is now defined in the function's namespace"
    print "function namespace : %s" % locals()
    print "name 'os' is still not defined in the module's namespace"
    print "module namespace : %s" % globals()

foo()

print "After calling foo(), name 'os' is still not defined in the module's namespace"
print "module namespace : %s" % globals()

class Foo(object):
    try:
        os
    except NameError, e:
        print "name 'os' is not yet defined in the class namespace"
        print "but we cannot inspect this namespace now so you have to take me on words"
        print "but if you read the code you'll notice we can only get there if we have a NameError, so we have an indirect proof at least ;)"
        print "name 'os' is not defined in the module's namespace neither obvisouly"
        print "module namespace : %s" % globals()

    import os
    print "name 'os' is now defined in the class namespace"
    print "we still cannot inspect this namespace now but wait..."
    print "name 'os' is still not defined in the module's namespace neither"
    print "module namespace : %s" % globals()

print "class namespace is now accessible via Foo.__dict__"
print "Foo.__dict__ is %s" % (Foo.__dict__)
print "'os' is now an attribute of Foo - Foo.os = %s" % Foo.os
print "name 'os' is still not defined in the module's namespace"
print "module namespace : %s" % globals()
```

Comment: I'm reading this about python namespaces : http://www.diveintopython.net/html_processing/locals_and_globals.html So when you refer to the "current namespace" you are referring to the `global` namespace not the `local` namespace even if it is called from inside a function?

Comment: @EmilDavtyan: no, I'm referring to the current namespace - the one where the import statement happens - whatever it is (function's local, module's global, class statement's body).

Comment: Look here for a simple script about imports and namespaces: http://pastie.org/8392105

Comment: Thanks, that really clarifies things. I did not know about the possibilities for the class namespace or how to explore it. Maybe you can put that script into the answer so that it remains here.

Answer (score 3):

When you use `import` you actually execute it's (module) code. So if you can control executing it (for example you only need `import` if some condition works) then put it anywhere you want.

```
if some_condition:
    import foo
```

If you always need (no condition) it, then put it at the top of your file.

For starters I would suggest always put `import` statement at the top of the file.

Comment: The module is only executed on the first import ("first" for the current Python process that is). It is then cached into `sys.modules` and subsequent imports will only do the local namespace binding part.

Answer (score 0):

When a module is first imported, Python searches for the module and if found, it creates a module object.

Depending on the size of the module, and the frequency with which it is used in your code, you may want to import it for once and forever at the top of your file, or you may want to import it when a particular condition is met.

The system memory is always constrained - If there is a high chance that the said condition for the module is going to be met in a very small number of cases, it will make sense to import based on the condition check.

This can be particularly useful if you need to import multiple **heavy** modules in your code which will each eat a lot of memory, but they are needed in different places. So rather than doing it like

```
import module1 
import module2

def foo1()
    module1.function()
def foo2()
    module2.function()
foo1()
foo2()
```

Try something like

```
def foo1()
    import module1 
    module1.function()
def foo2()
    import module2
    module2.function()
foo1()
foo2()
```

If the python modules are simple enough, it makes sense to include them at the top of the file - that ways, anyone else who is reading the code also gets a prior understanding of which all modules your current code uses.

Answer (score 0):

Imports are usually placed at the top of a file, like in other programming languages. Having them all together makes it easy to see the dependencies of a module at a glance.

However, since an `import` executes a module's code it may be an expensive operation, and for this reason you'll sometimes see imports inside functions. [NLTK](http://nltk.org) is a notoriously heavy module, so when I use that, I sometimes do

```
def _tokenize(text):
    import nltk
    return nltk.word_tokenize(text)

def process_some_text(text):
    if isinstance(text, basestring):
        text = _tokenize(text)
    # now do the actual processing
```

Because imports are cached, only the first call to `_tokenize` does the import. This also has the effect of making the dependency optional, since the `import` isn't attempted until the caller requests the relevant functionality.

Comment: Actually this "making the dependency optional" really means that the code will fail at any impredictable time instead of failing at process startup (which is the case when all your imports are at the top level).

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers: that can be documented, though, and the `ImportError` can be caught and translated into a friendlier error message.

Comment: yes indeed, but from experience chances are it will just crash the process (never saw such a case being explicitely documented nor handled).

Answer (score 0):

You can put it anywhere in the file **before** you use it.  You *should* **not** normally put it in loops, (as it will not do quite what you expect) but **may** put it in conditionals.  As the imported modules initialisation code is executed you might save a bit of time by only loading it if you know that you will need it.

You *may* put it within functions but if in function then it will only be in scope within that function. e.g.

```
>>> def f1():
...    import sys
...    print sys.version
...
>>> def f2():
...    print sys.version
...
>>> f2()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 2, in f2
NameError: global name 'sys' is not defined
>>> f1()
2.5.4 (r254:67916, Dec 23 2008, 15:10:54) [MSC v.1310 32 bit (Intel)]
>>> f2()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 2, in f2
NameError: global name 'sys' is not defined
>>>
```

A good convention to follow is to put it at the top of the files so that it is always available and easy to find.

You may also find, especially for testing package components that you may need to modify sys.path prior to some imports so that should be imported early.

A convention *I personally* find useful is to have all your system imports first then project package imports then local imports with appropriate comments between them.

If you `import` *modulename*, `from` *module* `import` *submodule* or `import` *module* `as` *alias* then import order should make no major difference **but** if you `from` *module* `import *` then  ***all bets are off*** as various modules can define the same name and the last will be what you get - this is just one of the reasons that it is discouraged.

Comment: The module is only executed once on the first import ("first" for the current Python process that is). It is then cached into `sys.modules` and subsequent imports will only do the local namespace binding part.

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers - The reason I said _should_ not was that it is a case where the code wouldn't do what it looked like it was doing.

Comment: I was just clarifying your "As the imported modules initialisation code is executed" assertion - quite a few newcomers think that `import` will reload/execute the module each time (or works like an #include directive or whatnot).